# Is there a way to disable the integrated keyboard on M1 MacBook Pro running Ventura without affecting an external Magic Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, macos-ventura

I have an M1 Max MacBook Pro, less than 1 year old, which has developed a fault with the integrated keyboard. As I am unable to get to an Apple Store at the moment, I have purchased a Magic Keyboard which I am using over the integrated keyboard, which is often activated by typing and is annoying.

As I am currently bedridden, there is no other way for me to position the keyboard whilst still having comfortable access to the trackpad.

I have tried:

- A keyboard cleaning app (worked too well, deactivated both internal and external)
- Mouse keys (only disabled the right side)
- Several Terminal commands for older versions of macOS (32-bit) none work with Ventura.

Is there any method to disable the integrated keyboard on the M1 Max MacBook Pro Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Install [karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and configure according to following link

- https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/disable-built-in-keyboard/